# How to handle event based on their type

Tags: java, design-patterns

Say I have and event class that contains data and the type of the event (from remote service)

```
public class Event{
  String StringData;
  Integer IntData;
  EvenType eventType;
}
```

where EventType is enum :

```
public enum EventType{
 NEW,UPDATE,DELETE
}
```

Say I have a pipeline that recessives stream of event and need to process the data inside the event according to its type. For example if it is new event need to save to db and log if it is delete event save it to file , so each event type has its own behavior need to implement.

for example:

```
List<Event> events = ...
events.forEach(e->??? ); //how to process the event based on its type
```

Comment: Have a look at [`switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statements.

Comment: Make an iEvent interface instead, and implement the correct functionality on implementations of the interface. Then, the receiving end just calls the interface method.

Comment: Assumes that the event knows how to handle itself, which it may not.

Comment: Ahh but without more info, we do not know. However the event should contain the info it needs to be handled

Comment: Not necessarily. What about UPDATE with multiple DB drivers .. e.g. Oracle vs Mongo.  The handler in that case would know what to do with the event -- the event carries the data.  But this is why there are different thoughts about architecture.

Comment: Events are information, not actors.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, this would be handled by a [`switch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement.

```
List<Event> events = ...
events.forEach(e->{
    switch (e.eventType) {
        case NEW:
          // do new thing
          break;
        case UPDATE:
          // do update thing
          break;
        case DELETE:
          // do delete thing
          break;
        default:
          throw UnexpectedEventType(); // just in case
    }
});
```

Comment: That would most likely violate the Open/Closed principle.